# PyCharm is getting freeze frequently

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide

While I'm using PyCharm 4.5. my many interval whole IDE getting freeze for few seconds  . i think this error because of allocated hip size
i was some time it getting 99% 
is their any way to increase allocated hips size

I have good system configuration :
16GB RAM , in most time about 10GB free,
CPU is AMD FX 8320,
SSD as storage

[image]